# AppsFlyer Unified DeepLink

Tags: react-native, appsflyer

i gone throught appsflyer document for unified appsFlyer.onDeepLink function there is nothing written in any document what should we unside that function. This is being used when user click on any specific url from outside app.
I've written below code but it's going inside deeplink function.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nWld.png)

Any document what should we in this function to get user to specific page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.